# How can i load the sub domains in php website

Tags: php

My website url is like this

```
example.com
```

Now i have to load the same files with a seperate sub domain name where the sub domain name is to be retrived from the database.

If the sub domain name is some **xyz** then i would like to load my website with this url

```
xyz.example.com
```

I would like work out it with php script or .htacess

Comment: if it is subdomain then why you need the `www`?

Comment: what type of webserver are you using? apache? nginx?

Answer (score -1):

Subdomains do not work with www. it needs to be in the format of subdomain.yoursite.com

By Definition:

In DNS hierarchy, a subdomain is a domain that is part of a larger domain. For example: www.yoursite.com is a domain name A subdomain is anything that replaces the www in a domain name. support.yoursite.com is a subdomain. www.support.yoursite.com is not a subdomain.

Comment: That's just wrong. Subdomains can also work with www., also you should name a source of your copy/pasted answer.

Comment: You Should Read Question Carefully. He Wants to Display Subdomain with www.xyz.example.com. Do Reply when you able to display subdomain start with wwww ??? Common Answers Does Not Need Sources.